# Приведение типов С и C#. Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type

Tags: c#, c, api, marshal

Вызываю из C# API библиотеки, к которой есть main.h
В указанном файле функция описана как

```
typedef struct { void *data; long long len; long long cap; } GSlice;

//printKeys :
extern __declspec(dllexport) GSlice printKeys(char* page, long long PerPage);
```

вызываю из C# так:

```
public struct GSlice
{
   public object data;
   public long len;
   public long cap;
}

[DllImport("wrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern GSlice[] printKeys(byte[] page, int perPage);

static void Main()
{
    int keyPerPage = 1000;
    string pageNumber = "1";
    GSlice[] Keys = new GSlice[keyPerPage];
    Keys = printKeys(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageNumber),keyPerPage);
    Console.WriteLine(Keys.Length);
}
```

На выходе без вызова Exception получаю:

```
Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Самая жуть в C# - это работа с внешними библиотеками. Судя по ошибке, ваша структура GSlice должна быть как то отмечена, что она так же является сишной структурой

Comment: @ArchDemon достаточно задать `LayoutKind`, но не только в этом здесь проблема.

Comment: @ArchDemon добавлял, успеха не дало.